# loop and remove if not match with some strings

Tags: javascript

This code doesn't work correctly. It's deleting the row 1,3,5,7,9 even if the value match or not and i want to delete every row that not contains any of that names

What i did wrong? i'm a newbie in such things.

```
var cuv1 = "John" ;
var cuv2 = "Jonny" ;
var cuv3 = "James" ;
var cuv4 = "Josh" ;
var cuv5 = "Jeff" ;
var cuv6 = "Joe" ;

var log = document.getElementsByName("log_str") ;
for(var i=0;i<log.length;i++)
{ 
        if (log[i].textContent.match(cuv1) || 
            log[i].textContent.match(cuv2) || 
            log[i].textContent.match(cuv3) || 
            log[i].textContent.match(cuv4) ||
            log[i].textContent.match(cuv5) || 
            log[i].textContent.match(cuv6)){}
        else { (log[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode).remove(); }
}
```

Problem Solved with a revers loop.
Thank you

```
for(var i=log.length-1; i>=0; i--)
```

Comment: probably because you're deleting the grandparent nodes that multiple rows are sharing?

Comment: `log` is a live NodeList. So you are basically mutating the list while iterating over it, which can lead to similar problems. Without more information, like seeing the HTML, we can't provide a solid solution though.

Comment: Use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) instead of `gEBN()`, it returns a static list.

Comment: Is the problem that your code removes rows even though they are all empty? None of the rows contains any of the words in your code.

Comment: i want to remove all the rows that not cantain any of that name even if is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that works:

```
var cuv1 = "John" ;
var cuv2 = "Jonny" ;
var cuv3 = "James" ;
var cuv4 = "Josh" ;
var cuv5 = "Jeff" ;
var cuv6 = "Joe" ;

var log = document.getElementsByName("log_str") ;
for(var i=0;i<log.length;i++)
{ 
    if (log[i].text.indexOf(cuv1) >=0 || 
        log[i].text.indexOf(cuv2) >=0 || 
        log[i].text.indexOf(cuv3) >=0 || 
        log[i].text.indexOf(cuv4) >=0 ||
        log[i].text.indexOf(cuv5) >=0 || 
        log[i].text.indexOf(cuv6) >=0){}
    else { (log[i].parentNode.parentNode).remove(); }
}
```

Comment: Why does this code work?  What's the problem with the OP's code?

Comment: In OP's code, the match() method searches a string for a match string, and returns the matches as an Array object. Got it.

Comment: And why is that a problem? Why does it matter what value it returns if all you want to know is if it matches or not?

Comment: We are checking for a condition, but we didn't specified any type of condition with matches returned as an Array object.

Comment: `.match()` returns an array only if a match was found. It returns `null` if it doesn't. An array evaluates to `true`, `null` evaluates to `false`. So `if (str.match(needle1) || str.match(needle2))` is perfectly valid to check whether `str` contains `needle1` or `needle2`. It may be not the most conventional way, but it works. You can try it for yourself: `"foobar".match("John") || "foobar".match("Steve")`

Comment: LOL, null doesn't refers to false as null is not a boolean value.

Comment: I said `null` *evaluates* to `false` (not that it *is* `false`). With that I meant that if evaluated as a boolean value, `null` is converted to `false`. Try it for yourself: `Boolean(null)`, or `if (null) { alert("Doesn't show"); }` or have a look at the specification: http://es5.github.io/#x9.2 . And before you say that nothing is converted to a boolean here: The result of the condition in the `if` statement is converted to a boolean: http://es5.github.io/#x12.5